# Question regarding executorService for asynchronous behavior

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

If I have a runnable that is define as calling an api that takes 10s to complete

```
    Runnable runnableTask = () -> {
        try {
            System.out.println("before");

            // call some api
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println("after");

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
```

and I have a `ExecutorService` that have 2 thread

```
   executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

   executorService.submit(runnableTask1);
   executorService.submit(runnableTask2);
   executorService.submit(runnableTask3);
```

is `runnableTask3` blocked by `runnableTask2` and `runnableTask1`?

or does `executorService` see that `runnableTask1` and `runnableTask2` is currently waiting for IO and will execute `runnableTask3`

Is there a way to make IO not block in executorService?

Even `newCachedThreadPool` only save on thread creation cost due to reuse

Comment: Why not try it out?

Comment: You should see this in the output. Runnable task 1 and 2 will block both threads of the executor service and it will not start task 3 until they are complete. A new thread will not be created.

Answer (score 1):

If you have blocking code, then it will block a thread of execution. In your example your executor has two threads, two of the tasks (1, 2, or 3) will be start and block. No other task will start until one of the executing runnable completes.

If you had three or more threads, then all three tasks will start about the same time, even if you only have 1 execution core available. That is because the OS will schedule tasks in a way similar to what you are thinking. Thread 1 starts running a task, and then it blocks. Now the thread goes into a "parked state" (there are a few states it might actually be in), so the OS is free to let one of the other two threads work.

There are different techniques to get around this. If you look at Swing/AWT, Dialogs can "block" the flow of a runnable on the EDT, but the GUI stays responsive and continues to process events.

For your simple example, I would suggest the simple solution to be use more threads than blocking tasks you expect to be submitting.

For IO you might use additional threading mechanisms so you don't block your executor.

As of java 19 another solution, are [virtual threads](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/java-loom-virtual-threads-platform-threads) this way java handles the threads in a manner similar to having additional threads, but without actually creating more threads. eg. [Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()) this still appears to be a preview feature in 19 though.